# Pass a Richtextbox to a Sub/Function

Tags: wpf, vb.net, function, textbox, richtextbox

Can anyone help - I want to be able to pass a richtextbox to a Sub/Function.

I have successfully used the following code to pass a textbox to a sub/function

```
Sub PassTextboxObject(ByVal textbox As TextBox)
    textbox.Text = "ABC123"
End Sub
```

I am unable to do this for a richtextbox?

I cannot use a normal textbox on my form, it has to be a richtextbox.

I'm using VB.NET in VS2010 professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this change : TextBox should be cahnged as RichTextBox to pass a richTextBox

Let `RichTextBox1` be your `RichTextBox` then you can use the sub as follows

```
    Sub PassTextboxObject(ByVal textbox As RichTextBox)
        textbox.Text = "ABC123"
    End Sub
```

In call:

```
PassTextboxObject(RichTextBox1)
```

Comment: Hi

Thanks for the reply - so simple!

I was letting the intellisence make suggestions, "richtextbox" wasn't one of them!

Thanks very much

John